# Custom order by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Below is the select statement

```
select * 
from #final
order by 
    case  
       when [Col1] in (select top 10 [Col1] from #take order by [Col2] desc) 
          then 0
          else 2
    end
```

My above select statement returns the result as below

```
            Col1                              Col2
            --------------------------------------
            App                              86748
            AppService                         832
            BK                               21227
            Cap                             160272
            Fukusima                          1634
            McBaa                             1727
            Others                            6718
```

However, I would like to get this result instead:

```
            Col1                              Col2
            --------------------------------------
            Cap                             160272
            App                              86748
            BK                               21227
            McBaa                             1727
            Fukusima                          1634
            AppService                         832
            Others                            6718
```

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Your ordering logic is not quite what you think it is doing. It is getting the top 10 rows of Col2 and putting those in some order followed by the rest of the data in some order. Why do I say "some order"? Because those two groups of data are not sorted at all. You need a second column in your order by. And that second column may need another case expression to get the values you want at the end.

Comment: I think: end, [Col2] desc will work..let me try.

Comment: That might work if "AppService" and "Others" are not in the top 10 query. But we have no of knowing because you didn't provide sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just differenced between the two types, but inside that type 0, there is no second order method. Just add then Col1 as second order, descending.

```
select * from #final
        order by 
        case when [Col1] in (select top 10 [Col1] from #take order by [Col2] desc) then 0
        else 2
        end, [Col2] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

With the below table structure

```
CREATE TABLE final
    ([col1] varchar(10), [col2] int)
;

INSERT INTO final
    ([col1], [col2])
VALUES
    ('App', 86748),
    ('AppService', 832),
    ('BK', 21227),
    ('Cap', 160272),
    ('Fukusima', 1634),
    ('McBaa', 1727),
    ('Others', 6718)
;
```

The below query will give exact results

```
select * from final
        order by 
        case when [Col1] in (select top 6 [Col1] from final order by [Col1] asc) then Col2 
        end desc, 
        [Col1] asc


col1       |    col2
-----------------------
Cap        |    160272
App        |    86748
BK         |    21227
McBaa      |    1727
Fukusima   |    1634
AppService |    832
Others     |    6718
```